# ggplot2: geom_bar(); how to alternate order of fill so bars are not lost inside a bar with a higher value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to position two bars at the same position on the x-axis and seperated out by colour (almost as if stacking).

However, instead of stacking I want the bar simply inside the other bar - with the smallest Y-value being visable inside the bar with the highest Y-value.

I can get this to work to some extent - but the issue is that one Y-value is not consistently higher across one of the two factors. This leads to bars being 'lost' within a bar with a higher Y-value.

Here is a subset of my dataset and the current ggplot code:

```
    condition hours expression freq_genes
 1      tofde     9         up         27
 2      tofde    12         up         92
 3      tofde    15         up        628
 17     tofde     9       down          0
 18     tofde    12       down          1
 19     tofde    15       down          0
 33      tofp     9         up       2462
 34      tofp    12         up        786
 35      tofp    15         up        298
 49      tofp     9       down        651
 50      tofp    12       down        982
 51      tofp    15       down       1034
 65       tos     0         up         27
 66       tos     3         up        123
 67       tos     6         up        752
 81       tos     0       down          1
 82       tos     3       down         98
 83       tos     6       down        594 


sf_plot <- ggplot(data = gene_freq, 
              aes(x = hours, 
                  y = freq_genes, 
                  group = condition,
                  fill = factor(expression,
                                labels=c("Down", 
                                         "Up"))))

sf_plot <- sf_plot + labs(fill="Expression")

sf_plot <- sf_plot + geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
                          width = 2.5, 
                          position = "dodge")

sf_plot <- sf_plot + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#9ecae1", 
                                            "#3182bd"))

sf_plot <- sf_plot + xlab("Time (Hours)")

sf_plot <- sf_plot + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 
seq(min(gene_freq$freq_genes), 
max(gene_freq$freq_genes),
by = 3))                                                         

sf_plot <- sf_plot + ylab("Gene Frequency")

sf_plot <- sf_plot + facet_grid(. ~ condition, scales = "free")

sf_plot <- sf_plot + theme_bw()

sf_plot <- sf_plot + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                       panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

sf_plot <- sf_plot + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))


# Print plot
sf_plot
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need `position = 'dodge'` in `geom_bar()`? Try `position = 'stack'` instead.

Comment: In my understanding, `'dodge'` puts bars side-by-side instead of stacked, but since you have a large width, they end up taking the space one from another and you only see the one "in front".

Comment: 'Stack' leads to the bars stacked on top of each other which is not what I want. Even when I put the bar width tiny this code still puts the bars inside each other (which is what I want) - I just want the dark blue bars to be visible inside the light blue when their Y values are smaller - e.g. at 21 hours panel 'tofde'

Comment: Your expected output is not crystal-clear, could you print or draw what you want to achieve ? Any crappy paint.exe draft would do the trick :-)

Comment: Have you considered adding some `alpha` value to make the colors transparent?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/lSKqhCf added photo to the album - basically I want the dark blue bar not to be hidden within the light blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `alpha = 0.5` to your `geom_bar()` statement to make the bars transparent. This will allow both bars to be seen. Adding that `alpha` statement and nothing else will produce what you're looking for, to make both overlaid bars visible. The colors, however, make seeing the two different bars challenging.

[image]

Another (and maybe better) option is to change the order in which the plot is created. If I recall correctly, `ggplot` will plot the bars in alphabetical or numeric or factor-level order. Here, your `expression` values are `c("Down", "Up")` and `"Down"` is being plotted first. If you force `"Up"` to be plotted first, you could resolve this, too.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- 
  read.table(text = "condition hours expression freq_genes
1      tofde     9         up         27
2      tofde    12         up         92
3      tofde    15         up        628
17     tofde     9       down          0
18     tofde    12       down          1
19     tofde    15       down          0
33      tofp     9         up       2462
34      tofp    12         up        786
35      tofp    15         up        298
49      tofp     9       down        651
50      tofp    12       down        982
51      tofp    15       down       1034
65       tos     0         up         27
66       tos     3         up        123
67       tos     6         up        752
81       tos     0       down          1
82       tos     3       down         98
83       tos     6       down        594") %>%
  mutate(expression2 = ifelse(expression == "up", 1, 2))

dat %>%
ggplot(aes(x = hours, y = freq_genes, group = condition, 
           fill = factor(expression2, labels=c("Up", "Down")))) +
  labs(fill="Expression") + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 2.5, alpha = 0.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#9ecae1", "#3182bd")) + 
  xlab("Time (Hours)") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(dat$freq_genes), 
                                  max(dat$freq_genes),
                                  by = 3)) + 
  ylab("Gene Frequency") + 
  facet_grid(. ~ condition, scales = "free") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "bottom", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Here, I've created a new column called `expression2` that is just a numeric version of `expression`. I changed the `fill` variable in `aes()` to match with those new labels. I left the colors in `scale_fill_manual()` the same as in your original statement and kept the `alpha` value. "Down" is being plotted on top of "Up" but in keeping the same colors with the `alpha` value, both bars are easier to see. You can play with the legend to display "Down" before "Up" if that's necessary.

[image]

Note that providing machine readable data goes a long way in allowing others to help you out. Consider using `dput()` to output your data next time rather than pasting it in. Also note that you can "chain" together `ggplot()` statements with a `+`. This makes code much more compact and easier to read.